# How to read content from a file and then save them in a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, hex

Not very good at programming. Need to change the script code. It is necessary to read the contents of the file and split it into separate keys, and then save them in a file. Thank you in advance for your help!!!

'text.txt'

File:

0200e7c810f4553fe1722522f8dcfc8e810757ef427efefef79bdf08ddf3700fd5
0216b3e68fed004b2fea2119cdbb8ab2393dfe8fc99398da18e40b6e949e9e1278
022bbf0fcde9bcba6e1038b78bd6906ed00be95d1a6f912a7352f5aca2d7bb6bbc
021060631ef4a610aebc3c9e24f5b0e33dcd0eb422b8223dbd75c1e6edfd21dd72
0218cbb66d6a417890aea6bf5f8a83a4d181a89c5aba8121e20def5b42c311514e
025d8ea956802ed00ebec42b480c0eb77c6ada6ed3fceb40e5fff9aed0fa31c6b4
02264a8c56551abeb68d6112863249857a4360c38528d02b9313988ba062e6efed

```
import binascii

with open('text.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()
compressed_key_hex = text.split('\n')

computed_uncompressed_key = []

p_hex = 'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F'
p = int(p_hex, 16)
x_hex = compressed_key_hex[2:66]
x = int(x_hex, 16)
prefix = compressed_key_hex[0:2]

y_square = (pow(x, 3, p)  + 7) % p
y_square_square_root = pow(y_square, (p+1)//4, p)
if prefix == "02":
    y = (-y_square_square_root) % p
else:
    y = y_square_square_root

computed_y_hex = hex(y)[2:66]
computed_uncompressed_key = "04" + x_hex + computed_y_hex

with open('result.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(computed_uncompressed_key))
```

**I get the error:**

```
===================== RESTART: D:\detailALL\03\Bit06.py =====================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\detailALL\03\Bit06.py", line 12, in <module>
    x = int(x_hex, 16)
TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base
>>>
```

Comment: `x_hex` is a byte-array (python3 read() returns byte-arrays), you need to decode it to a string before using `int` on it

Comment: As @rdas said, `x_hex` needs to be a string. Were you looking to concat the string within that `[2:66]` slice?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a `list` rather than a `str`. In the following code `x_hex` is a list.

```
x_hex = compressed_key_hex[2:66]
```

So you need to convert the `list` to `str`, you can do that using the following:

```
x_hex = ''.join(compressed_key_hex[2:66])
```

I guess the following might be your required solution:

```
import binascii

with open('text.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()
compressed_key_hex = text.split('\n')
print(compressed_key_hex)
computed_uncompressed_key_list = []
p_hex = 'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F'
p = int(p_hex, 16)
for val in compressed_key_hex:
    x_hex = val[2:66]
    x = int(x_hex, 16)
    prefix = val[0:2]

    y_square = (pow(x, 3, p) + 7) % p
    y_square_square_root = pow(y_square, (p+1)//4, p)
    if prefix == "02":
        y = (-y_square_square_root) % p
    else:
        y = y_square_square_root

    computed_y_hex = hex(y)[2:66]
    computed_y_hex = computed_y_hex.zfill(64)
    computed_uncompressed_key = "04" + x_hex + computed_y_hex
    computed_uncompressed_key_list.append(computed_uncompressed_key)
with open('result.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(computed_uncompressed_key_list))
```

`text.txt` file:

```
0200e7c810f4553fe1722522f8dcfc8e810757ef427efefef79bdf08ddf3700fd5 
0216b3e68fed004b2fea2119cdbb8ab2393dfe8fc99398da18e40b6e949e9e1278 
022bbf0fcde9bcba6e1038b78bd6906ed00be95d1a6f912a7352f5aca2d7bb6bbc 
021060631ef4a610aebc3c9e24f5b0e33dcd0eb422b8223dbd75c1e6edfd21dd72 
0218cbb66d6a417890aea6bf5f8a83a4d181a89c5aba8121e20def5b42c311514e 
025d8ea956802ed00ebec42b480c0eb77c6ada6ed3fceb40e5fff9aed0fa31c6b4 
02264a8c56551abeb68d6112863249857a4360c38528d02b9313988ba062e6efed
```

`result.txt` file:

```
0400e7c810f4553fe1722522f8dcfc8e810757ef427efefef79bdf08ddf3700fd5c9b034d2aa9ee1ef7b2346e8fc9c0245a8746a92bfdbb472fc98397477551ced
0416b3e68fed004b2fea2119cdbb8ab2393dfe8fc99398da18e40b6e949e9e12780126dfa95d2d9ab8fc055ce158f1d2ef51c2a012413b3f88a6365f375cf903f8
042bbf0fcde9bcba6e1038b78bd6906ed00be95d1a6f912a7352f5aca2d7bb6bbcf4a39790075ce43dc08fbf0ecc9cc732415e6b066c3b8b8d960b8548e8a612b7
041060631ef4a610aebc3c9e24f5b0e33dcd0eb422b8223dbd75c1e6edfd21dd723f873c976d071939edf8450124da64c3d9a1b35fb070761b01a5bace7d741588
0418cbb66d6a417890aea6bf5f8a83a4d181a89c5aba8121e20def5b42c311514efb4f8645c503e7a39954e977f7af8e802a5ec44ce3084cb6fb4e133a79733e77
045d8ea956802ed00ebec42b480c0eb77c6ada6ed3fceb40e5fff9aed0fa31c6b4e7c279c9d2c3e731803a4dde91a0d9409e49b1cbec3c7ac536a3783d9518d737
04264a8c56551abeb68d6112863249857a4360c38528d02b9313988ba062e6efeddbd8a97a8762f6a1add1ea6f549b61316fe675fc703d49f597a91ad620f7627a
```

Comment: Actually `x_hex` is a `bytes` object - not a `list`. `bytes` objects need to be `decode` to string. Not `join`

Comment: In the code I saw the line `compressed_key_hex = text.split('\n')`, which returns a `list`, and he is trying the slice the list in the line `x_hex = compressed_key_hex[2:66]`. This is what I understood, it it right

Comment: Please tell me what needs to be changed in the code?

Comment: you need to change the line `x_hex = compressed_key_hex[2:66]` to `x_hex = ''.join(compressed_key_hex[2:66])`

Comment: @Jeril I changed as you said, but the result I get is that the list is created from each digit. That is, from "1". https://pastebin.com/FM8wgd2m
Need to have a list with 130 digits?

Comment: can you share the output of `print(compressed_key_hex)`

Comment: `with open('result.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(computed_uncompressed_key))`

I need to save the result to a file, please help me change the code. I think something needs to be changed here, but I'm not good at programming

Comment: @Jeril  I found this code at the link: https://repl.it/HeAZ/0
I want to change this code so that i can save uncompressed public keys as a result to a file: 'text.txt'
Please help me how can this be done?

Comment: I have updated my solution based on your requirement, please have a look at it. let me know if you have any issues

Comment: @Jeril  When using this value:
0216b3e68fed004b2fea2119cdbb8ab2393dfe8fc99398da18e40b6e949e9e1278

We get a wrong result (129 digit):
0416b3e68fed004b2fea2119cdbb8ab2393dfe8fc99398da18e40b6e949e9e1278126dfa95d2d9ab8fc055ce158f1d2ef51c2a012413b3f88a6365f375cf903f8

It should be 130 digits, that is, the correct result should be like this:
0416b3e68fed004b2fea2119cdbb8ab2393dfe8fc99398da18e40b6e949e9e12780126dfa95d2d9ab8fc055ce158f1d2ef51c2a012413b3f88a6365f375cf903f8
It is necessary that the number "0" be added to "hex (y)", tell me how to do this?

Comment: @Jeril Everything is working ! Thank you very much !